# Typescript Object inference over vue template not working

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

My Object type is defined with keys as string type but when looped over the vue template, typescript/vue infers it as type number and string. Please refer the screenshot. Due to this wrong type inference of 'number', I am not able to assign the key to different html attributes

Does anyone have an idea on how to correct this setup?
[image: Wrong Type Inference]

My package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxx",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "run-p type-check build-only",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test:unit": "vitest",
    "build-only": "vite build",
    "type-check": "vue-tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.vitest.json --composite false",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "format": "prettier --write src/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "pinia": "^2.1.4",
    "plotly.js-dist": "^2.25.1",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.3.2",
    "@tsconfig/node18": "^18.2.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.2.6",
    "@types/jsdom": "^21.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.17.0",
    "@types/plotly.js": "^2.12.26",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^8.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.3",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.1",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.4.0",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.15.1",
    "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vite": "^4.4.9",
    "vitest": "^0.33.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.6"
  }
}
```